# symfony2 : Register without logging the user in PUGXMultiUserBundle from the FOSUserBundle

Tags: symfony, controller, fosuserbundle, overriding, pugxmultiuserbundle

I need to disable the default behaviour of logging the new user after registration
I know that this is [FOSUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle) question but I'm using the [PUGXMultiUserBundle](https://github.com/PUGX/PUGXMultiUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md) which override the default controller

```
class RegistrationUserTwoController extends Controller
{
 public function registerAction()
 {
   return $this->container
              ->get('pugx_multi_user.registration_manager')
              ->register('Acme\UserBundle\Entity\UserTwo');
  }
}
```

Any response will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Nevertheless the use of MultiUserBundle, you should still override the default FosUserBundle `AuthenticationListener` that takes care of authenticating the users during `FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_COMPLETED` and `FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_CONFIRMED` events:

The class is found here:
vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/FOS/UserBundle/EventListener/AuthenticationListener.php

You can use this class as basis of your own listener, and use `fos_user.listener.authentication` as the service id among the `parameters` in your your bundle's `services.yml` file setting your class.

```
 parameters:    
     fos_user.listener.authentication: Acme\FooBundle\Authentication\MyAuthenticationListener
```

If you are not familiar with service overriding, then this tutorial will help you: 
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/override.html#services-configuration